# Remove specific tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml similar to below where I have a tag named in "plural" enclosing an array of tags named in "singular". Eg marketHierarchyLevels & marketHierarchyLevel , archiveLevels & archiveLevel.

I want to use xslt to identify the these patterns and remove the "plural" tag. Is this possible via XSLT?

**Input**

```
    <customer>
        <marketReference>
            <marketHierarchyLevels>
                <marketHierarchyLevel>
                    <marketName>NATIONAL</marketName>
                    <level>0</level>
                    <marketId>1</marketId>
                </marketHierarchyLevel>
                <marketHierarchyLevel>
                    <marketName>WEST DIVISION</marketName>
                    <level>1</level>
                    <marketId>8211</marketId>
                </marketHierarchyLevel>
            </marketHierarchyLevels>
        </marketReference>
        <archiveReference>
            <archiveLevels>
                <archiveLevel>
                    <marketName>NATIONAL</marketName>
                    <level>0</level>
                    <marketId>1</marketId>
                </archiveLevel>
                <archiveLevel>
                    <marketName>WEST DIVISION</marketName>
                    <level>1</level>
                    <marketId>8211</marketId>
                </archiveLevel>
            </archiveLevels>
        </archiveReference>                 
    </customer>
```

**Expected Output**

```
        <customer>
            <marketReference>

                    <marketHierarchyLevels>
                        <marketName>NATIONAL</marketName>
                        <level>0</level>
                        <marketId>1</marketId>
                    </marketHierarchyLevels>
                    <marketHierarchyLevels>
                        <marketName>WEST DIVISION</marketName>
                        <level>1</level>
                        <marketId>8211</marketId>
                    </marketHierarchyLevels>

            </marketReference>
            <archiveReference>

                    <archiveLevels>
                        <marketName>NATIONAL</marketName>
                        <level>0</level>
                        <marketId>1</marketId>
                    </archiveLevels>
                    <archiveLevels>
                        <marketName>WEST DIVISION</marketName>
                        <level>1</level>
                        <marketId>8211</marketId>
                    </archiveLevels>

            </archiveReference>                 
        </customer>
```

**Latest XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:m="http://xml.comcast.com/saleschannelmanagement/services"
    xmlns:typ="http://xml.comcast.com/saleschannelmanagement/types">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name() = concat(name(*), 's')]">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[concat(name(), 's') = name(..)]">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}s">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>





</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***-- edited in response to changed requirement --***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[name() = concat(name(*), 's')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[concat(name(), 's') = name(..)]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}s">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Personally, I would prefer a safer approach - albeit one that requires you to know the structure of the incoming XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="marketHierarchyLevels | archiveLevels">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="marketHierarchyLevel | archiveLevel">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}s">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. I'll check this out.

Comment: @PunterVicky Upon reread, I may have misunderstood your question. The above will remove *any* wrapper element whose name ends with "s". Did you mean to limit this to elements whose name is the plural form of their children? If yes, you should change `<xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), string-length(name()), 1) ='s']">` to `<xsl:template match="*[name() = concat(name(*), 's')]">` Note that this only looks at the name of the first child.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes I would like to limit it only to parent-child element that have everything exactly the same except s. The parent should have s and child should not have s. Sorry I now modified my expected output slightly as I overlooked it. All the child elements must be renamed with s after removal of parent element.

Comment: @PunterVicky That's quite a change. Can one assume that all child elements have the same name? -- P.S. I repeat my recommendation to name the affected elements explicitly and avoid "clever" solutions that might produce unexpected results due to coincidence.

Comment: Hi Mike , yes all the child elements have the same name. In my example , all child element under "marketHierarchyLevels" should have name "marketHierarchyLevels" and all child elements under archiveLevels must have name archiveLevels.

Comment: Thanks Michael. One last question. I see namespaces after I used this. I was trying to combine this with your previous response ,  but still trying to remove the namespaces.

Comment: @PunterVicky Instead of the first template above, use the first template from your previous question.

Comment: I did it , Mike , but I see the namespace in the newly created elements (marketHierarchyLevels and archiveLevels). I have pasted the latest xslt , also I want to remove customerReturn similar to previous example. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}s">` instead of `<xsl:element name="{name()}s">`. If that doesn't solve it, I will want to see an example of the real input.

Comment: Works great. Thanks again!!